# how to create a multilabel dataset from 3 dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have 3 dataframes and they have only one column: `text`

**df1**

```
text
I have a car
he has a bus
```

*df1.shape = (10000,1)*

**df2**

```
text
He likes orange
She ate the banana
```

*df2.shape = (10000,1)*

**df3**

```
text
Microsoft is a TI company
SpaceX is a Aerospacial company
```

*df3.shape = (10000,1)*

I want to create another dataframe, merging `df1`, `df2` and `df3` to get this as output:

```
text                               vehicle      fruits     companys
I have a car                          1           0           0
he has a bus                          1           0           0
He likes orange                       0           1           0
She ate the banana                    0           1           0
Microsoft is a TI company             0           0           1
SpaceX is a Aerospacial company       0           0           1
```

**output.shape = (30000,4)**

How can I do this?

Comment: on what basis; 3 new column came into the picture ?

Comment: df1 has 10000 string  having some kind of vehicle on it.  You can think as `df1['vehicle'] =1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"text":["I have a car","he has a bus"]})
df1["vehicle"] = 1
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"text":["He likes orange","She ate the banana"]})
df2["fruits"] = 1
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"text":["Microsoft is a TI company","SpaceX is a Aerospacial company"]})
df3["companys"] = 1

df4 = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
df4.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df4.index = range(0,df4.shape[0])
```

Output of df4

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve what OP desired.

IMO what OP wants is to check if there are vehicles, fruits or companies the the strings.

In order to do that, one will need to first define what is a vehicle, a fruit or a company. For that, one can create a list for each (the lists can be improved)

```
vehicles = ["car", "bus", "motorcycle", "airplane", "train", "boat", "ship", "helicopter", "submarine", "rocket", "spaceship"]
fruits = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grape", "strawberry", "watermelon", "cherry", "peach", "pear", "mango", "pineapple"]
companies = ["Microsoft", "Apple", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook", "Tesla", "SpaceX", "Boeing", "Airbus", "Lockheed", "NASA"]
```

Now, with the lists, one can merge the dataframes with `pandas.concat`

```
df_merge = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

[Out]:
                              text
0                     I have a car
1                     he has a bus
2                  He likes orange
3               She ate the banana
4        Microsoft is a TI company
5  SpaceX is a Aerospacial company
```

And now, with the merged dataframe, one can check if the values in the lists above are present in the rows.

We start with the `vehicles`

```
df_merge['vehicles'] = df_merge['text'].apply(lambda x: sum([x.count(i) for i in vehicles]))

[Out]:
                              text  vehicles
0                     I have a car         1
1                     he has a bus         1
2                  He likes orange         0
3               She ate the banana         0
4        Microsoft is a TI company         0
5  SpaceX is a Aerospacial company         0
```

Now we move to `fruits`

```
df_merge['fruits'] = df_merge['text'].apply(lambda x: sum([x.count(i) for i in fruits]))

[Out]:

                              text  vehicles  fruits
0                     I have a car         1       0
1                     he has a bus         1       0
2                  He likes orange         0       1
3               She ate the banana         0       1
4        Microsoft is a TI company         0       0
5  SpaceX is a Aerospacial company         0       0
```

Finally, we do it for `companies`

```
df_merge['companies'] = df_merge['text'].apply(lambda x: sum([x.count(i) for i in companies]))# Print the result

[Out]:

                              text  vehicles  fruits  companies
0                     I have a car         1       0          0
1                     he has a bus         1       0          0
2                  He likes orange         0       1          0
3               She ate the banana         0       1          0
4        Microsoft is a TI company         0       0          1
5  SpaceX is a Aerospacial company         0       0          1
```

---

**Notes:**

- Even though out of scope for this example, this approach has, at least, one limitation. More specifically, if a string has an orange vehicle, for example `She has an orange bus`, it will detect both a vehicle and a fruit. If one wants to accommodate that, one will have to do it from here.
- Apart from the point above, there are more that can happen, however, to consider all, one would need to have access to the full dataframe.